# mysql, selecting from different tables (FULL OUTER JOIN equivalent)?

Tags: mysql

I have a basic apache 2 lamp service, running mysql and php5.

I have 2 tables, one called `articles` that contains columns `id`(primary key, auto increment), `title, posted, author_id, extract, body` and another table that's called `authors` that contains columns `id`(primary key, auto increment), `name, img, bio`.

I want to make a select statement that returns articles.title, articles.posted, articles.extract, articles.body, authors.name. Now normaly I would do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but it wouldn't work, and after googling a bit I found out that you can't do that in mysql, google suggests using a `UNION` or combining `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

I tried, but somehow I can't get it to work. I can't make a union, because my tables have different numbers of columns (there are many articles from the same author).

I also tried this:

```
SELECT articles.title authors.name FROM articles
LEFT JOIN authors ON articles.author_id = authors.id
UNION
SELECT articles.title authors.name FROM articles
RIGHT JOIN authors ON articles.author_id = authors.id;
```

but I get an error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.name FROM articles`

Any insight on how to make this work would be great.

I would also like to sort my results by `articles.posted`, `DESC`, but I can probably figure that out on my own once I get the initial statement right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot some `,`:

```
SELECT articles.title, authors.name FROM articles
                     ^---here
LEFT JOIN authors ON articles.author_id = authors.id
UNION
SELECT articles.title, authors.name FROM articles
                     ^---here
RIGHT JOIN authors ON articles.author_id = authors.id;
```

Your version is trying to `SELECT articles.title AS authors.name`, and aliases cannot contain `.`

Comment: ugh, time to take a break. Works now, thanks for the help